# How to match images corresponding to sounds in android?

Tags: android

Here is my java coding.. please help me.. I am doing a project for children.

```
package com.VRG;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Animalsgame extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // int answer=0;
    Button voice;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    TextView time;// count down timer
    ImageView img_view1;
    ImageView img_view2;
    ImageView img_view3;
    ImageView img_view4;
    static int index = 0;
    static int index1 = 0;
    static int noOfLapse;
    static int count = 0;
    static boolean isSoundPlay;
    CountDownTimer CountDownTimer;
    int idx;
    Integer next;
    int temp1, temp2;

    private Random random;
    private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> sounds;
    private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> tempSounds;

    final int[] imageViews = { R.id.img_view1, R.id.img_view2, R.id.img_view3,
            R.id.img_view4 };// Array of image views

    int[] Animals_images = { R.drawable.cow, R.drawable.lion, R.drawable.dog,
            R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.elephant, R.drawable.camel,
            R.drawable.rhinos, R.drawable.horse, R.drawable.donkey,
            R.drawable.wolves }; // Array of Animal images

    String Animals_images_string[] = { "cow", "lion", "dog", "sheep",
            "elephant", "camel" };

    String mfile_sounds_string[] = { "cow", "lion", "dog", "sheep", "elephant",
            "camel" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        time = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.time);
        img_view1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_view1);
        img_view2 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_view2);
        img_view3 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_view3);
        img_view4 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_view4);

        img_view1.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_view2.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_view3.setOnClickListener(this);
        img_view4.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Count down timer
        voice = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.voice);// Animals sounds

        voice.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Initialise Lapse counter
        noOfLapse = 0;
        isSoundPlay = true;

        random = new Random();

        sounds = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cow));
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lion));
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dog));
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sheep));
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.elephant));
        sounds.add(MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.camel));

        tempSounds = (ArrayList<MediaPlayer>) sounds.clone();

        enableDisableImageView(false);

    }// End of Oncreate method

    public void setDuration(int duration) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        enableDisableImageView(true);

        if (v == img_view1) {

            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
            count++;
            time.setText("");
            if (CountDownTimer != null) {
                CountDownTimer.cancel();
            }
            enableDisableButton(true);
        }
        if (v == voice) {
            loadImages();
            // answer++;
            freezeButtonAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButton();
            countDown();
            // enableDisableButton(true);
        }

        if (v == img_view2) {
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
            count++;
            enableDisableButton(true); // Re-enable buttons
        } else if (v == voice) {
            loadImages();
            countDown();
            enableDisableButton(false);
        }

        if (v == img_view3) {
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
            count++;
            enableDisableButton(true); // Re-enable buttons
        } else if (v == voice) {
            loadImages();
            countDown();
            enableDisableButton(false);
        }

        if (v == img_view4) {
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
            count++;
            enableDisableButton(true); // Re-enable buttons
        } else if (v == voice) {
            loadImages();
            countDown();
            enableDisableButton(false);
        }

        if (count > 4) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            setDuration(0);
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.claps);
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }
            }
            mp.start();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Score : " + count,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // set the message to display
            alertbox.setMessage("Game Over..! Do you want to play again?");
            // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        // do something when the button is clicked
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            if (mp != null) {
                                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                                    mp.stop();
                                }
                            }
                            count = 0;
                            // Intent i = new Intent(VRGActivity2.this,
                            // VRGActivity2.class);
                            // startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

            // set a negative/no button and create a listener
            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        // do something when the button is clicked
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            if (mp != null) {
                                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                                    mp.stop();
                                }
                            }
                            finish();
                            // Intent i = new Intent(VRGActivity2.this,
                            // VRGActivity1.class);
                            // startActivity(i);

                        }
                    });

            // display box
            alertbox.show();
            enableDisableButton(false);
        }
    }// End of voice on click

    private void countDown() {

        CountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(6000, 10000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (isSoundPlay) {
                    // freezeButtonAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButton();
                    isSoundPlay = false;
                }
                time.setText("" + "" + millisUntilFinished / 10000);

            }

            public void onFinish() {

                // time.setText("UP");
                setDuration(0);
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time Up",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                isSoundPlay = true;

            }// End of on finish
        }.start(); // End of countDown Constructor
    }// End of countDown method

    public void enableDisableButton(Boolean state) {
        voice.setEnabled(state);

    }

    public void enableDisableImageView(Boolean state) {
        img_view1.setEnabled(state);
        img_view2.setEnabled(state);
        img_view3.setEnabled(state);
        img_view4.setEnabled(state);
    }

    private void loadImages() {
        // img_view1.setImageResource(Compulsory_Animals_images[answer]);

        Random rng = new Random(); // Random function
        List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            while (true) {
                next = rng.nextInt(9);
                index = next;
                if (!generated.contains(next)) {
                    generated.add(next);
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViews[i]);
                    iv.setImageResource(Animals_images[next]);

                    break;
                }// End of if
            }// While loop
        }// End of for loop
    }

    public void freezeButtonAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButton() {
        enableDisableButton(false); // disable buttons
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(tempSounds.size());
        mp = tempSounds.get(randomInt);

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Index: "+sound_index,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        temp1 = randomInt;
        temp2 = temp1;
        tempSounds.remove(randomInt);
        temp1 = temp2;
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpalmost) {
                // mpalmost.release();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    // while back pressed the task is refreshed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.v("44444", "onBackPressed Called");
        if (mp != null) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // saveState();
        Log.v("11111111", "onPause Called");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.v("111111", "onStart Called");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("222222", "onResume Called");

        // freezeButtonAndPlaySoundThenUnfreezeButton();

    }

    @Override
    // if key down happens
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        {
            Log.d("333333", "onKeyDown Called");
            onBackPressed();
            finish();
            // calling the OnBackpressed method called
        }

        return true;
    }

}// }
```

I am using four image views and one sound button.
 In which if i click the sound button the random sound
 get raised and all of a sudden the four image views will
 be filled by four images which is obtained randomly. 
 Now I have to match the sound corresponding to the sound.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean by "match"? Do you want to ask the kid to tell the correct animal whose sound is like that?

Comment: Yes! and Actually, The kid must press the sound button and one animal sound will be raised and simultaneously four animal images will be displayed. The kid have to here the animal sound and must choose animal image corresponding to the sound heard...! plz help me..!

Comment: Hey, you are the programmer, so you are supposed to know the correct match,right? In you program, You can set an ID on your every sound and image resource and hash these two value groups. Now when the kid plays the sound ,you know what the corresponding image should be.

Comment: Thanks for ur good idea.. Than q so much.. And one more question.. Is there any other idea without using hashmap?? Because I am beginner in developing field

Comment: Any how than q..! and Have you did any editing in my code? and one unwanted question: Is there any possibility of chatting in this website..?

Comment: I am also a new man here, but I think we can chat, as long as we are talking about programming. I just wrote some codes for your reference, showing my idea(of course, your code has referred). I don't have Eclipse on hand and It's difficulty for me to edit your code. I am not a programmer now, just an enthusiast. Sorry.

Comment: I am going to be off the work now. I may check this thread on my way back home. Hope it helps.

Comment: Than q so much.........! Will meet you soon.....1

Comment: OK Ok.. cool.. And thanks four ur help and if possible can i have your friendship? and I think you said you are going out from this website.. so take care....

Comment: I am not able to ask or post any questions.. Any one plz help me.....!

Comment: you'd better ask for help from the administrator.  send him emails if you have problems with your account. I an not able to help...

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate response and how can i contact administrator?

Comment: look at the bottom of the home page, do you see the "contact" link?

Comment: Ya boss.. I mailed. Let see what happens.. Actually this website helped me a lot.. I miss this website and also the people who help out me here including you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I say hash, I don't mean that you have to setup a hashmap. That's not a light weight solution. "To hash" means that you have to setup a relationship between these two value groups. Here in Android, every resource has been compiled with an ID in class R. You can use two int[] variables.I.e:

```
//keeps the element at the same position matching.
final int[] animals = new Int[]{R.drawable.cow, R.drawable.lion, ...};
final int[] sounds = new Int[] {R.raw.cow,R.raw.lion, ...};
```

When the kid presses the button, you would get a random sound file ID. I.e.

```
int index = new Random.nextInt(0,TOTAL_RESOURCE_NUMBER);
```

Now play the sound, "MediaPlayer.create(sounds[index]);"
Link the correct imageView with this index. `int imageIndex = new Random(0,4); imageViews[imageIndex].setDrawable(animals[index]);`

Now you know the imageView with the imageIndex is the imageView we want and you can check.

Comment: Actually, Your answer is for one image.. But the Kid need to choose one image from the collection of four image according the sound produced..!

Comment: Well, I just set the correct imageView that matches the sound. It is not difficulty to set the other 3 imageViews. Something like for(int i=0;i<4;i++) { if(i!=imageIndex) imageViews[i].setDrawable();} Of course, you need to exclude the correct image resource in this loop.

Comment: On this forum, nobody is supposed to write all the code for you. You are supposed to implement your own logic. The ohters may give you some tips or hints. Hope you understand.

Comment: Do you get my idea? You might as well try to setup your own code. The core idea is that you have to use some variables to record the sound file and the imageView index,so in this way, you can check if the kid picks the correct imageView.

Comment: Hmm.. Than q.. Than q for ur help...! and I want to chat with you in this site.. How should I?

Comment: Look at the bottom of the site. You will find the chat channel, however, you can't start chatting because your reputation is less than 20.I am also a freshman here, perhaps there's some other way to chat but I don't know yet.... That's Ok, it is free for you to post any questions related to programming here. You had better describe your problem in a concrete way instead of posting so many code. You know, it is difficulty to understand someone else's long piece of codes in a short while.

Comment: Oh.. Now i understand.. Here after I will post the important part of the problem.. And Actually i thought, that the full coding will help to understand the logic....! any how thanks yar...!

Comment: I having one different doubt.. Actually I can i find the question which is asked rit now! in stack over flow